# WP feed Facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I need help with facebook API,

I have a plugin Flow-Flow Social Stream, I create new API from manual there method 2: https://docs.social-streams.com/article/46-authenticate-with-facebook.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K78W5.png)

But after paste all information on plugin I see only this error message:

Sorry, an error occurs from Facebook API: (#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.

I don't know what more for this do now, please I there someone who Can advice me best solution or any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is an indication that there is no proper page access token being used for the API requests. To be able to access content from just any public page, you would need to submit your app for review of that “feature” first. But with a page access token it isn’t “public” access any more, the page token proves that you have admin access to the particular page in question … so if you still get that error, it most likely means you did not create a proper page access token.

Double-check that, and debug your access token to see if it is actually a page access token for the page in question, and what permissions it includes. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: Thank you I had to Extend Access Token and debug again, than generate key works.